# Get Python Flask to return values from json/dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, flask

I have stored my output in a dictionary, like this:

```
str3 = "Triangle, Bow, Boat"
str1 = "some text regarding body parts"
str2 = "some text regarding themes"


d={}
key=str3
d[key] = str1
d[key]=[d[key]]
d[key].append(str2)
print(d)
```

**{'Triangle, Bow, Boat': ['some text regarding body parts', 'some text regarding themes']}**

And I am trying to get it to be returned to html so that it appears separated on three lines as such:

**Triangle, Bow, Boat
some text regarding body parts
some text regarding themes**

I have tried creating an entire string as output and using new line and break characters, but this didn't work.

So I'm trying to use some combination of jsonify and json.dump in order to get these to display properly in html.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do:

```
string = key + '<br>' + d[key][0] + '<br>' + d[key[1]
return '<p>' + string '</p>'
```

Comment: I gave this a try...it doesn't seem like the html characters are being translated.  I end up with:        <p>Triangle, Bow, Boat<br> some text regarding body parts <br>some text regarding themes</p>

Answer (score 0):

above code should work with the + sign added

```
string = key + '<br>' + d[key][0] + '<br>' + d[key[1]]
return '<p>' + string + '</p>'
```